# Right side of toolbar button. Button crosses right screen border

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitoolbar

Toolbar button right side. Button crosses right screen border. iPhone SE and 7 don`t look similar.

Toolbar included in another View, maybe it is a case.
[image: iPhone 7]

if you can see, little part of button visible on SE and full button in iPhone7

[image: iPhone SE]

I use flexible space bar ui button between "Edit" and "Done" buttons.
Please, help me to find out what`s wrong in this case.

Comment: are you using auto layout

Comment: @MOMMH i don`t know what is it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't user Auto Layout, I think you are using frame.

You could get the screen width via magic number since the size of iPhone SE and of 7 are different.

```
CGFloat kScreenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
```